# QT Creator Linker Error: Link2019 File Not Found

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qt-creator, header-files

I'm not quite sure where my problem is.

I'm using Qt Creator for an OpenGL project, and for the first time, I have tried adding another few classes  to my project. I've added both header and implementation files : terrain.h, terrain.cpp, imageloader.h, and imageloader.cpp.

I think my problem lies in my .pro file:

```
HEADERS += glwidget.h \ 
imageloader.h \
terrain.h
SOURCES += glwidget.cpp main.cpp \
imageloader.cpp \
terrain.cpp

QT += opengl
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += console c++11
INCLUDEPATH += "../include"
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

RESOURCES += shaders.qrc
```

When I run qmake, there are no errors.

Then, when I build the project (after cleaning, running qmake), I get the following error:

```
glwidget.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static class Terrain * __cdecl GLWidget::loadTerrain(char const *,float)" (?loadTerrain@GLWidget@@CAPEAVTerrain@@PEBDM@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl GLWidget::initializeGL(void)" (?initializeGL@GLWidget@@MEAAXXZ)
```

Qt Creator also says: File Not Found glwidget.obj

However, the problem really seems to be with the terrain class, or how it interacts with glwidget.

When I remove all references to terrain, the build works fine.

However when I add the following line to glwidget.cpp in the initializeGL() method, the LINK2019 error appears:

```
terrain = loadTerrain("test.bmp", 20);
```

terrain is defined in glwidget.h as an instance of the Terrain class from terrain.cpp:

```
Terrain* terrain;
```

And loadTerrain is defined in glwidget.h as:

```
static Terrain* loadTerrain(const char* filename, float height);
```

Interestingly, this error occurs even when the implementation of loadTeerain is commented out.

Here are a few more things I've tried:

When I run clean before or after qmake, or delete the .obj files in the build folder, there is no change. I have noticed that glwidget.obj as well as terrain.obj do appear when the project is rebuilt.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you would like to see any of my files.

**EDIT:** The problem persists even after making the loadTerrain() method nonstatic.

**EDIT 2** I also seemed to have forgot the second error that it is throwing, though I'm not sure that this will be any more help:

```
debug\program2.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

debug is the folder where the .obj appear and program2 is the name of the project.

---

**FIXED!** It turns out that making the method static was the problem. You can't have a static method declared in header files that are going to be used by multiple sources in the way that I was doing. I replaced:

```
static Terrain* loadTerrain(const char* filename, float height);
```

with

```
Terrain* GLWidget::loadTerrain(const char* filename, float height);
```

As well as changing the subsequent calls to the method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems you miss implementation of loadTerrain in cpp file?

Comment: I did have an implementation commented out, however uncommenting it does not seem to help.

Comment: Having implementation commented out means you have no implementation. Could you please post related parts of your header and source files updated?

Comment: Do you receive the same error now?

Comment: I was about to reply with the requested lines of code, but that made me realize the problem. When I made the method non-static and uncommented the implementation, I left it as a call and declaration to loadTerrain rather than GLWidget::loadTerrain. That seems to have fixed the problem now! Thanks for your help! I've spent so long on this problem.

Comment: >> LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals - it doesn't give additional information, just a number of linker errors. So the problem is solved now?

Comment: Yeah I added EDIT 2 right before I saw your last comment and fixed it. I will add a third edit explaining the fix. Thanks!

Comment: Better to add your own answer

Comment: I'm pretty new to posting questions to Stack Overflow, but it seems that user625...'s answer pretty much covered it. Should I still post an answer?

Comment: If you find answer useful you can upvote. If it answers your question, you can accept it. If you didn't find answer, you can post your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the function `static` you gave it internal linkage. This means the definition of your function will only be found in the translation unit in which it is defined (i.e, `terrain.cpp`) and not `main.cpp`. Remove the static keyword.

This is very easy to confirm with `objdump`. Say you have `test.h`:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H
#define _TEST_H

static void a_func();

#endif
```

`test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

void a_func()
{
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

void a_func()
{
}

int main()
{
}
```

You'll notice that you won't get a function redefinition error. We can compile each file separately to inspect the objects:

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o 
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

Both will show `a_func`:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_ZL6a_funcv>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   90                      nop
   5:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   6:   c3                      retq
```

Now what about the final binary?

`g++ main.o test.o`

`objdump -d ./a.out`

```
00000000004005b6 <_ZL6a_funcv>:
  4005b6:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005b7:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005ba:   90                      nop
  4005bb:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005bc:   c3                      retq   

00000000004005bd <main>:
  4005bd:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005be:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005c1:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4005c6:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005c7:   c3                      retq   

00000000004005c8 <_ZL6a_funcv>:
  4005c8:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005c9:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005cc:   90                      nop
  4005cd:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005ce:   c3                      retq   
  4005cf:   90                      nop
```

It appears twice! This is why you don't make functions static in a header file meant to be shared across multiple translation units.

Comment: That makes sense that making the method static would cause a problem. However, I made it nonstatic, cleaned the project, ran qmake, and rebuilt, and the problem remains...

Comment: Disregard my last comment. Once I made it non-static, I had to remember to add the GLWidget:: prefix to the method call, declaration, and implementation. Once I did that and reraran qmake, it worked! I spend a crazy amount of time on the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd upvote your answer but I lack the requisite reputation!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you lack implementation of function `loadTerrain()` in glwidget.cpp:

```
Terrain* loadTerrain(const char* fileName, float height)
{
   // your implementation here
}
```

You may look [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/20938/qimage-get-data-transfer-from-basic-c) for a sample.

Comment: I did have an implementation, but it was commented out. I uncommented it (and made it non-static to follow the advice given above) to no luck.